# Injective homomorphism between groups gives injective homomorphism between quotient groups

Tags: group-theory

This is an exercise from A First Course in Abstract Algebra by J. Rotnam.

let A and B be groups, let A' $\triangleleft$ A and B' $\triangleleft$ B be normal subgroups, and let $\alpha:A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism with $\alpha(A') \subseteq B'$.

(i) Prove that there is a well defined homomorphism $\alpha_*:A/A'\rightarrow B/B'$ given by $\alpha_*:aA' \rightarrow \alpha(a)B'$

(ii) Prove that if $\alpha$ is surjective, then $\alpha_*$ is surjective.

(iii) Prove that if $\alpha$ is injective, then $\alpha_*$ is injective.

I have managed to prove (i) and (ii). But I'm stuck on (iii).

Attempt:

Suppose $\alpha(a_1)B'=\alpha(a_2)B'$. Then $\alpha(a_1^{-1}a_2) \in B'$. But we need to show that $a_1^{-1}a_2 \in A'$ right? I can't see how to use injectivity of $\alpha$ to do this. Also, isn't it possible that the entire A is mapped into B' injectively, in which case the $\alpha(A) \in B'$, then all $\alpha(a)B'$ are the same coset, and (iii) would be false?

Comment: This is because (iii) is not true (consider when $B'=B$).

Comment: Alright hahaha thanks. Any idea what the author might have been intending to say?

Comment: Perhaps for (iii) he wanted to insist $A'=\alpha^{-1}(B')$?

Comment: did you mean $A' \subseteq \alpha^{-1}(B')$? Because if $A' = \alpha^{-1}(B')$ we could conclude (iii) is true i think?